# Durandal: Implement multiple/alternate shells for pop-out window

Tags: durandal

My Durandal application will have an "open for printing" feature on a particular form, where it will open a separate window and present the form without the application's normal navigation elements. I am having trouble figuring out how to implement this in my application.

I'm still fairly new with Durandal at this point. My understanding is that I'm opening another instance of my SPA, in a separate window, but using a different shell. I want to duplicate as little functionality as possible.

Here is my `main.js`, sanitized of proprietary code and marked up to indicate how I currently envision the solution:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: { 'durandal':'../lib/durandal/js', /* et al */ },
    shim: { 'bootstrap': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'jQuery' } },
});

define(
    ['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'viewmodels/config'],
    function (system, app, viewLocator, config)
{
    //>>excludeStart("build", true);
    system.debug(true);
    //>>excludeEnd("build");

    app.title = 'My Application';

    app.configurePlugins({ router: true, dialog: true });

    //!! Do something here to determine which shell to use.
    var shellRoute = 'viewmodels/shell' //!! Unless popout window, then 'viewmodels/shell-nonav'

    app.start().then(function() {

        viewLocator.useConvention();

        $.when(config.init()) // config.init returns $.ajax().
        .then(function () { app.setRoot(shellRoute); })

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.hash` to get the hash of the selected route, then set `shellRoute` based on the hash.